# Remove element from objects in javascript multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, element

I have read several solutions to this problem here. When I try it, I continue to receive an error for the pop() method.

I have what is essentially a multidimensional array in javascript.
I am tasked with returning the array with the sensitive info removed (e.g. remove the SSN, in this example)

I thought I could use a foreach loop, and the pop() function to remove the last element of the child arrays, the SSN.

testing it using node on the commandline, the stdout is telling me that element.pop() is not a function. i've tried it with pop(), slice(), filter(), all with no success.

when running $> node filename.js

H:\Apache2\htdocs\test\filename.js:50
noppi[i] = element.pop();
^

TypeError: element.pop is not a function

```
let recs = [
    {
        ID: 1,
        NAME: 'John',
        EMAIL: 'john@example.com',
        SSN: '123'
    }, {
        ID: 2,
        NAME: 'Sally',
        EMAIL: 'sally@example.com',
        SSN: '456'
    }, {
        ID: 3,
        NAME: 'Angie',
        EMAIL: 'angie@example.com',
        SSN: '789'
    }
];

let i = 0;
let noppi = [];

recs.forEach(element => {
    noppi[i] = element.pop();
    i++;
    
});

console.log(noppi);
```

Comment: array of objects is not multidimensional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of sounding redundant, I'll briefly reiterate what the earlier answers have already stated.

The input data structure isn't a multi-dimensional array <del>`[ [ ... ], [ ... ] ]`</del> , it's an array of objects `[ {...}, {...} ]`. So you can't use Array methods like `.pop()` on the objects `{...}`.

Here's a simple one-liner that uses `.forEach()` and `delete`.

```
recs.forEach(obj => delete obj.SSN)
```

`delete` is an operator with one purpose: to remove an object's property like for example `SSN: '123-45-6789'`. Simple and perfect.

Note, `.forEach()` mutates the array, meaning that it's the original data being changed (see Minja's comment).

```js
let recs = [
    {
        ID: 1,
        NAME: 'John',
        EMAIL: 'john@example.com',
        SSN: '123'
    }, {
        ID: 2,
        NAME: 'Sally',
        EMAIL: 'sally@example.com',
        SSN: '456'
    }, {
        ID: 3,
        NAME: 'Angie',
        EMAIL: 'angie@example.com',
        SSN: '789'
    }
];

recs.forEach(obj => delete obj.SSN);

console.log(recs)
```

Comment: I'm not quiet sure what the other answers are trying to achieve, but if you're not trying to make a shallow copy of the array and want to just remove a key from the existing objects, this is the right answer.

Comment: @Minja good point, I added a note about mutation thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
recs.forEach(element => {
    noppi.push = element;
});
```

You are trying to use pop() on an object not an array

Answer (score 0):

As per your need you need to remove SSN from your object, try below code it should work for you.

```
recs.forEach(element => {
 const { SSN, ...rest } = element;
    noppi.push(rest);
});
```

Here we are removing SSN from object and rest will push in noppi.

Comment: Thank you! This works 
[
  { ID: 1, NAME: 'John', EMAIL: 'john@example.com' },
  { ID: 2, NAME: 'Sally', EMAIL: 'sally@example.com' },
  { ID: 3, NAME: 'Angie', EMAIL: 'angie@example.com' }
]
but, i don't understand why.  Could you please share a URL to any docs that explain the approach you're using here? a quick search illustrates that you're using the Spread Operator. , but what is the significance of SSN, in (aside from being the "key" i want to remove)? 
const { SSN, } 

Thank yoU!

Comment: Here basically which key you need to remove, define at the time of destructuring    other wise rest will pass in data.

Comment: how do i accept solution? I have "Answer your question" and "add comment". If i click the up arrow for the answer, i get an alert that i dont have enough rep to do that.